# Laravel-Excel exported excel sheet doesn't convert date values in column to date

Tags: php, excel, laravel-4, laravel-excel

I am using [laravel-excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export) to export data in my database to an Excel worksheet. Columns containing dates are not interpreted as dates in Excel, so when I go to import this Excel file using laravel-excel, these columns aren't parsed and formatted correctly.

An example table:

```
table name: items
id  |   name    | some_date
===========================
1     Boxes       2014-11-13 17:00:00
2     Pickles     2016-12-01 13:30:00
...
```

My Laravel code:

```
Excel::create('SomeTitle', function($excel) {

    $items = Item::all()->toArray();

    $excel->sheet('SheetName', function($sheet) use($items) {
        $sheet->fromArray($items, null, 'A1', true);
    });
})->export('xls');
```

Now, in the exported Excel file, column C (which is "some_date") will contain a date like `2014-11-13 17:00:00`, but Excel will not recognize this as a date - so when I import the tile using laravel-excel, it will not automatically be converted to an instance of [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon).

When I use `$sheet->setColumnFormat(array('C' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'));` and import the Excel file again, laravel-excel will now recognize and convert the date to a Carbon instance, but the date, time and days will be completely off!

The only way Excel will recognize the cells in the column as dates is if I click on the column, and click away. Excel then automatically converts it to a date.

How can I ensure that the `some_date` column is automatically converted to a date when I export the file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return extra columns as Carbon instances add the following to your model;

```
public function getDates(){
    return array('created_at','updated_at','some_date');
}
```

This will return it as an instance of Carbon automatically. So in theory whenever it tries to print out the instance it should be printed out as a string.